# Perl getpwnam fails in sub

Tags: perl, getpwnam

So i'm trying to use getpwnam() to search etc/passwd for a username in a sub, and return true if it exists. I keep getting the error "Use of uninitialized value in getpwnam".

```
sub nameSearch
{
$search = $_;
@name = getpwnam($search);
if ( ! defined $name[0])
{
return 0;
}
else
{
return 1;
}
}
```

I'm passing a chomped string into this sub. I've tried just using `@name = getpwnam($_[0])`
and `@name = getpwnam($_)`

I know as a fact that string i'm passing exists as a username in /etc/passwd and the code works when its not in a sub.

Comment: Can you show us how you're calling this `sub`, and how it compares to the inline version that purportedly works?  Also, why aren't `$search` and `@name` local to the `sub`?  ie. `my $search` and `my @name`?

Comment: I'm a bit of a noob at Perl, didn't realize that was how local variables were called! Thanks for bringing it to my attention!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're passing user name as a parameter then you should check first element of `@_` which is `$_[0]`.

`$_` is global variable conveniently used as implicit `foreach` variable and function can use it in case no parameter was sent to it. Actually this is common behavior for most perl core functions which take `$_` if no explicit argument is given.

```
sub nameSearch {
  my ($search) = @_;
  $search = $_ if !@_;

  my @name = getpwnam($search);

  return @name ? 1 : 0;
}

print nameSearch("user") ? "exist" : "doesn't exist";
```